# My form is not submitted correctly in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms, laravel-form

I am trying to submit an user profile update form in my Laravel project. But while I click on the submit button that page just reload but not submit the form. also not given any error.

**html code**

```
 <form action="{{ url('/profile-update') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="csrf-token" value="{{ Session::token() }}" />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Image</label>
        <input id="edit_form_image" type="file" class="form-control" name="edit_form_image">
    </div><!-- end form-group -->

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name <span class="form_mendatory">*</span></label>
        <input id="edit_form_name" type="text" class="form-control" name="edit_form_name" value="{{Auth::user()->name}}">
    </div><!-- end form-group -->

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Spouse Name</label>
        <input id="edit_form_spouseName" name="edit_form_spouseName" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
    </div><!-- end form-group -->

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email <span class="form_mendatory">*</span></label>
        <input id="edit_form_email" type="email" name="edit_form_email" class="form-control" value="{{Auth::user()->email}}">
    </div><!-- end form-group -->

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Contact No <span class="form_mendatory">*</span></label>
        <input id="edit_form_contact_no" type="text" name="edit_form_contact_no" class="form-control"  value="{{Auth::user()->contact_no}}">
    </div><!-- end form-group -->

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>National ID</label>
        <input id="edit_form_NID" type="text" name="edit_form_NID" class="form-control"  value="">
    </div><!-- end form-group -->

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Profession <span class="form_mendatory">*</span></label>
        <input id="edit_form_profession" type="text" name="edit_form_profession" class="form-control"  value="{{Auth::user()->profession}}">
    </div><!-- end form-group -->

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Address</label>
        <input id="edit_form_address" type="text" name="edit_form_address" class="form-control"  value="">
    </div><!-- end form-group -->

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-orange" value="Save Changes">
</form>
```

If I change the input type from `submit` to `button` then no reload or submit of the form.

**route**

```
Route::post('/profile-update','userController@profile_update');
```

**userContoller.php**

```
$request->validate([
        'edit_form_image' => 'required|file|max:1024',
        'edit_form_name' => 'required',
        'edit_form_profession' => 'required',
        'edit_form_email' => 'required',
        'edit_form_contact_no' => 'required',
    ]);

    $request->edit_form_image->store('logos');

    $user = Auth::user();

    $user->name = $request->edit_form_name;
    $user->avatar = $request->edit_form_image;
    $user->email = $request->edit_form_email;
    $user->contact_no = $request->edit_form_contact_no;
    $user->profession = $request->edit_form_profession;
    $user->spouse_name = $request->edit_form_spouseName;
    $user->edit_form_address = $request->edit_form_address;


    $user->email = request('email');
    $user->contact_no = request('contact_no');
    $user->profession = request('profession');

    $user->save();
```

Where is the problem?

Anybody can help ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From first look, 
1.) it's like validation failing error
2.) can you remove "/" from the Route::post and form actions.
3.) CSRF hidden input pass like (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf).

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    ...
</form>
```

If above solutions not work then, can you confirm that the request will sent to the server or any error on console.

Comment: It's a validation related problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes post method not woking while update better use patch method to update.You need to pass user id because which user id you want to update.

**HTML**

```
<form action="{{ route('updateProfile',$user->id)') }}" method="patch" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
```

**route**

```
Route::post('/profile-update/{id}','userController@profile_update')->name('updateProfile');
```

I hope this i may help you.

Comment: Try this..Use csrf token.